# .threads and parallelProcessing in camel

Tags: apache-camel

**Route :**

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolBuilder(context).poolSize(10).maxQueueSize(100).build("myCustom-Thread");

from("direct:myROute")
.aggregate(myAggregationStrategy).constant(true)
           .threads().executorService(executorService)
           //.parallelProcessing().executorService(executorService)
           .process(myProcessor)
     .end();
```

I am trying to process the processor logic to run in multithreaded, but in the available options from camel I am getting confused on below behavior

***Using .threads with executorService***
though it is getting me 10 threads as per the executorService configuration, but all threads are running one by one. which gives me the same behavior as of single thread and also degrading the performance

**Using .parallelProcessing with executorService**
all threads(10) are running in parallel, but caller thread(main thread of route) get called while threads(parallel processing threads) are still doing their job.
which is not correct.

how can I handle this scenario, in which I can call the caller once all threads are complete their job?

Comment: How does the route look like that calls `direct:myRoute`? When using the `direct` endpoint to call "sub-routes", those sub-routes run in the thread of the calling route. If the calling route is multi-threaded, then you have already achieved your desired behavior.